# The fastest algorithm to calculate the $C^n$

Tags: algorithms, algebraic-number-theory, computational-complexity, fast-fourier-transform

I am looking for the fastest algorithm to calculate the $$C^n$$ where the $C$ is some algebraic constant.

For example it can be $$C=\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2}$$ or one of the root of $$x^5+x^2-1=0$$

If $$C=2$$ the algorithm is very simple and it has complexity $O(\ln n)$. The same is for any other natural number I assume.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "calculate," but yes, the $O(\log n)$ approach (the method of repeated squaring) will work in most cases.

Comment: Exactly, if you know $p(x)$, the minimal polynomial of $C$, then $C^n$ can be computed by applying repeat squaring in $\mathbb{K}[x]/(p(x))$.

Comment: About Fibonacci numbers, for instance: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2081266/44121

Comment: Thanks just spend time on reading of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring article based on comments. It may be helpful for others as well:

Comment: And also many thanks for the Fibonacci numbers article. I was looking for the similar thing.

Comment: excuse me but how exactly are you computing $2^n$ in $O(\log n)$ steps if it takes $O(n)$ steps to write the result ?

Comment: Actually here we made an assumption that each number is a single symbol. And only operation count is calculated on those symbols. But complexity of writing of number is a different task and it depends on many factors including the base etc.