# How to generate specific members of a natural number series

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

I have a series I can generate sequentially if I pair elements with Pell numbers. If I pair them with $1,2,5,12,29,...$ (Pell numbers, $p_n$) and call elements of this series $q_n$, then $q_n=q_{n-1}+p_{n-1}$ where $q_0=1$.

$$1\quad 
2\quad 
4\quad 
9\quad 
21\quad 
50\quad 
120\quad 
289\quad 
697\quad 
1682\quad 
4060\quad 
9801\quad 
23661\quad 
57122$$

I would like to generate any $q_n$ directly. I can get $p_n$ directly but so far my formula depends on knowing $q_{n-1}$ beforehand. Can the $n^{th} q$ be generated directly?

Comment: Yes, $q_n=\dfrac{2+(1+\sqrt2)^{n+1}+(1-\sqrt2)^{n+1}}4$

Comment: @J. W. Tanner Your formula works. How did you find it?

Comment: I will try to answer in a few hours.  Are you interested in how I found the formula or mathematical justification of it?  In your definition of Pell numbers, is $p_0=1$?  (Usually $p_0=0$, but I can work with your definition)

Comment: @J. W. Tanner Your answer let me generate the pairs: $$1,1\quad 
2,2\quad 
4,5\quad 
9,12\quad 
21,29\quad 
50,70\quad 
120,169\quad 
289,408\quad 
697,985\quad 
1682,2378\quad 
4060,5741\quad 
9801,13860\quad 
23661,33461\quad 
57122,80782\quad 
137904,195025\quad 
137904,195025\quad 
332929,470832\quad $$ for input to a formula I developed: $$A=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-2)k\quad B=2(2n-1)k+2k^2\quad C=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k+k^2$$ to make it generate Pythagorean triples where $B-A=\pm1$

Comment: There is some discussion of Pythagorean triples and Pell numbers on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_number) page

Comment: I'm familiar with the page. I was referred to it and found an answer to the same sort of [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399189/looking-for-the-best-way-to-find-pythagorean-triples-where-b-a-pm1) for Euclid's formula in which all the inputs to find $B-A=\pm1$ are Pell numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Pell numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellNumber.html) ([OEIS A000129](http://oeis.org/A000129) $ 0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 29, 70, ...)$ are usually given by

$P_0=0, P_1=1, P_n=2P_{n-1}+P_{n-2}=\dfrac{(1+\sqrt2)^n-(1-\sqrt2)^n}{2\sqrt2}$.

The [Pell-Lucas numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_number) ([OEIS A002203](http://oeis.org/A002203)  $2,2,6,14,34,82,198,...)$ are usually given by

$Q_0=2, Q_1=2, Q_n=2Q_{n-1}+Q_{n-2}=(1+\sqrt2)^n+(1-\sqrt2)^n.$

Your $q_n$ ([OEIS A024537](http://oeis.org/A024537) $1, 2, 4, 9, 21, 50,...)$ is $\dfrac{Q_{n+1}+2}4.$

Comment: I know how to generate pell numbers. I never paid attention to Pell-Lucas numbers. Your final equation involving $Q$ to obtain $q$ is the same as the comment above and it works, so you get the prize. Thank you.

Comment: Did you realize this answer was given by the same J.W. Tanner as above?  Fractions with half-Pell-Lucas numbers as numerators and Pell numbers as denominators approach $\sqrt2:  \frac11, \frac32, \frac75, \frac{17}{12}, \frac{41}{29}, \frac{99}{70}, ...$

Answer (score 1):

One way to find a formula is to convert the system of difference equations into first order difference equations - the Pell numbers $p_n=2p_{n-1}+p_{n-2}$ is a second order difference equation. To do this, we introduce a dummy sequence
$$a_n=p_{n-1}$$
for $n\ge1$; this lets us write
$$\begin{align*}
a_n&=p_{n-1}\\
p_n&=2p_{n-1}+a_{n-1}\\
q_n&=q_{n-1}+p_{n-1}.
\end{align*}$$
Now the reason we like this first order system is that we can define
$$x_n=\begin{pmatrix}a_n\\p_n\\q_n\end{pmatrix}$$
so that for $n\ge 2$
$$x_n=\begin{pmatrix}p_{n-1}\\2p_{n-1}+a_{n-1}\\q_{n-1}+p_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&2&0\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}x_{n-1}.$$
Letting $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&2&0\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$, we get
$$x_n=Ax_{n-1}=A^2x_{n-2}=\cdots=A^{n-1}x_1.$$
Now all that remains is to compute $A^{n-1}$ by writing as Jordan Normal Form, i.e. finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jordan Normal Form or eigenvalues. Your final equation also seems to make reference to a prior value of $x$ which is what I do not need.